# Working with raw file on Python. ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 5038848 into shape

Tags: python, image, numpy, raw

I wrote code in Python programming language. This code should first open the raw file and output it as an image. Next, you need to split the pixels into RGB values and calculate the 3x3 matrix for color correction. But before that, you need to do a black level correction.
The picture shows the approximate operation of the algorithm. Raw file is 14 bit and has RG pattern.
Link to raw file: [text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TQQqcHVBw1OdQR9rR04MRanFdEeNXPkX/view?usp=drive_link)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltCJI.png)
The code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def open_raw_file(raw_file_path, width, height):
    with open(raw_file_path, 'rb') as file:
        raw_data = file.read()

    # Assuming raw data is in RGB format, each pixel consists of 3 bytes (R, G, B)
    # Adjust the data format based on your specific raw file format if necessary
    image_data = np.frombuffer(raw_data, dtype=np.uint8)
    image_data = image_data.reshape((height, width, 3))

    return image_data

def apply_black_level_correction(image_data, black_level):
    corrected_image_data = np.maximum(image_data - black_level, 0)
    return corrected_image_data

def split_into_channels(image_data):
    red_channel = image_data[:, :, 0]
    green_channel = image_data[:, :, 1]
    blue_channel = image_data[:, :, 2]
    return red_channel, green_channel, blue_channel

def calculate_color_correction_matrix(image_data):
    # Assuming a 3x3 color correction matrix is required
    # Calculate the matrix based on your specific algorithm or requirements
    color_correction_matrix = np.eye(3)  # Identity matrix for demonstration purposes
    return color_correction_matrix

def save_image(image_data, output_path):
    image = Image.fromarray(image_data)
    image.save(output_path)

# Main code
raw_file_path = 'macbeth_2592x1944_RG.raw'
output_image_path = 'output_image13.jpg'
width = 640  # Adjust as per your raw file dimensions
height = 480  # Adjust as per your raw file dimensions
black_level = 20  # Adjust the black level value as per your requirement

# Open raw file and convert it into an image
image_data = open_raw_file(raw_file_path, width, height)

# Apply black level correction
corrected_image_data = apply_black_level_correction(image_data, black_level)

# Split into RGB channels
red_channel, green_channel, blue_channel = split_into_channels(corrected_image_data)

# Calculate color correction matrix
color_correction_matrix = calculate_color_correction_matrix(corrected_image_data)

# Perform color correction
red_channel_corrected = np.dot(red_channel, color_correction_matrix[0])
green_channel_corrected = np.dot(green_channel, color_correction_matrix[1])
blue_channel_corrected = np.dot(blue_channel, color_correction_matrix[2])

# Merge color channels back into image
output_image_data = np.stack((red_channel_corrected, green_channel_corrected, blue_channel_corrected), axis=2)

# Save the corrected image
save_image(output_image_data, output_image_path)
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\lab13.py", line 43, in <module>
    image_data = open_raw_file(raw_file_path, width, height)
  File "C:\Users\DC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\lab13.py", line 11, in open_raw_file
    image_data = image_data.reshape((height, width, 3))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 5038848 into shape (480,640,3)
```

So i try to run this code with:

1. As I said raw file is 14 bit, but I run it with 8 bit (didnt help).
2. I tried with size: w:640, h:480 and w:2592, h:1944 (original raw size) (Didnt help).
3. I tried to change reshape function changing image_data = image_data.reshape((height, width, 3)) to image_data = image_data.reshape(height, width).
   None of that helped me.

Comment: I don't think RAR format is a very good way of sharing as they are known for their ability to contain viruses.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Firstly, you can use virustotal. Secondly i cannot upload RAW file to goodle disc without archieving it.

Comment: Are you sure the raw file is supposed to be RGB? From the filename, the dimensions should be `2592*1944=5038848` from your error message, it would seem that the array you are reading has exactly that size, so sounds to me like it only has one channel?

Comment: Your file seems to be 5038848 bytes long, so it is likely not 14-bit but 8-bit and not RGB but grey and 2592x1944 which multiply together to make that size.

Comment: @FlyingTeller My teacher said that is RGB image, but he also pointed it is RG pattern(maybe not). He just said that is RGM image and i shuld make color correction, when I said about this error he couldnt answer me. And I do undestand that I am reaching 5038848 size.

Comment: @MarkSetchell My teacher said it is 14 bit image. And one interesting thing is that, I opend this raw with other code and saw that it was GREY, I said it to him but he said this raw is RGB.

Comment: Sounds like you need to convince your teacher. what is the filesize. if he claims that it is `2592*1944` pixels and 3 channels per pixel with 14 bit per pixel then the filesize should match this spec. If it is significantly lower (as would be the case if it was only greyscale), there is a good argument. Also talk to other students, was any of them able to read RGB?

Comment: If it's RGB, you need to divide the filesize in bytes by 3. That gives 1679616. So if you type *"divisors of 1679616"* into https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=divisors+of+1679616 you will find the possible heights and widths of your image. None of those you suggest are in the list.

Comment: @FlyingTeller I won't be able to tell him that because he's over-conceited. And if I do not show the solution to the problem and start arguing with him about it, he will put 0%. This task is only for me, but in the group 90% of people have problems with these tasks because they were not explained in any way, they just gave 5 words on the task and said to do it.

Comment: You should also provide a raw hex dump of the first 20-30 bytes so we can see if it has the signature of a compressed file or any distinguishing characteristics. You can use `xxd YOURFILE.RAW | head 4` or upload it to http://hexed.it

Comment: @MarkSetchell Why don't they fit? There is also a division with the sizes that I indicated 2592 and 1944.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't allow for 3 RGB bytes per pixel. It only allows 1.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I got this like code fragment: unsigned char ucDataBlock[33] = {
 // Offset 0x00000000 to 0x00000020
 0xE0, 0x0F, 0xC0, 0x18, 0xA0, 0x0F, 0x40, 0x18, 0xA0, 0x0F, 0xC0, 0x17,
 0x20, 0x0F, 0xC0, 0x18, 0x20, 0x0F, 0xC0, 0x17, 0xE0, 0x0D, 0x40, 0x17,
 0x60, 0x0E, 0x40, 0x17, 0x20, 0x0E, 0xC0, 0x17, 0x60
};

Comment: I think you would do better to share your file in a non-proprietary format not renowned for containing viruses - maybe GZIP. If you would like folk to help you, I think it's generally a good idea to make it easy for them.

Comment: @Rotem You have my vote already - I wish folks would recognise quality and effort more often.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you for your appreciation. I suppose that in many cases the OP appreciates our answers, but don't know the system well enough for accepting the answer. Some folks are not aware to the inbox messages. Some just like getting their homework done, and move on, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The image you have shared is 10,077,696 bytes, and assuming the filename is correct and the image is 2592x1944, that means it has two bytes per pixel because

```
2592 x 1944 x 2 = 10,077,696
```

So, if I unpack it as 16-bit greyscale with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
convert -depth 16 -size 2592x1944 gray:macbeth_2592x1944_RG.raw -verbose info:
```

I obtain:

```
Image:
  Filename: gray:macbeth_2592x1944_RG.raw
  Format: GRAY (Raw gray samples)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 2592x1944+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Type: Grayscale
  Endianness: Undefined
  Depth: 16-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 15-bit                    <--- HERE
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 5038848
    Gray:
      min: 808  (0.0123293)         <--- HERE
      max: 16256 (0.248051)         <--- HERE
      mean: 3913.4 (0.0597147)
...
...
```

I can now see it contains 15-bits of legitimate data per pixel and the greyscale range of the samples is 808..16256.

That would make it dark, as nothing exceeds 25% of the full 16-bit range of 0..65535. So I would apply auto-levels to correct the contrast and make it into JPEG like this:

```
convert -depth 16 -size 2592x1944 gray:macbeth_2592x1944_RG.raw -auto-level a.jpg
```

[image]

---

It therefore looks like 2592x1944 is the correct geometry, and there are 16-bits per pixel. The name implies the 16-bits might be 8-bits of red and 8-bits of green or some Bayer-like mash-up of the two. The black level of 800 in the description looks like it is correct because the range of the grey levels is 808..16256, so that would mean the correct range is 8..15,456.

---

Coming back to your Python, that would mean you need to use:

```
width = 2592 
height = 1944
```

and the following to read 2 bytes per pixel and reshape correctly:

```
image_data = np.frombuffer(raw_data, dtype=np.uint16).reshape((height, width))
```

Comment: Thank you for that information I hope it will help in conversation with teacher

Answer (score 1):

We may figure out the image format from the `readme.txt` and from the file name.

Content of readme.txt:

```
Bayer pattern = RG
black level = 800
bpp = 16
bit depth = 14
```

We may conclude that the image is in [Bayer CFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) format (probably RGGB Bayer alignment).
The black level is 800.
There are 16 bits per pixel (we may assume each pixel is uint16 element).
The white level is 2**14-1 = 16383 (applying bit depth = 14).

The file name is `macbeth_2592x1944_RG.raw`.
We may conclude that the resolution is 2592x1944 (width=2592, height=1944).

---

In Bayer mosaic format, each pixel may be either red, green or blue (it's kind of grayscale image format, but the filter on each pixel determines the color).
For converting Bayer to RGB, we may use OpenCV [cv2.cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html) method.
The process of converting from Bayer to RGB is named [Demosaicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosaicing).
The input to the Demosaicing algorithm is single channel image, and the output is 3 channels RGB image.

---

Reading the raw image - make sure to read 2592x1944 pixels with `uint16` type:

```
width = 2592
height = 1944

def open_raw_file(raw_file_path, width, height):
    with open(raw_file_path, 'rb') as file:
        raw_data = file.read()

    image_data = np.frombuffer(raw_data, dtype=np.uint16)  # According to the readme.txt bpp = 16 (16 bits per pixel).
    image_data = image_data.reshape(height, width)  # The image is in raw Bayer format - before Demosaicing there is only one channel.
```

---

After the black level correction apply Demosaicing:

```
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(corrected_image_data, cv2.COLOR_BayerBG2RGB)  # COLOR_BayerBG2RGB gives the best results.
```

---

There is an issue with the way color correction is applied, but since the matrix is an eye matrix, let's skip the details.

---

Before saving the image as JPEG format, we have to convert the image to type uint8 (pixel range [0, 255]).
We may apply linear transformation followed by rounding, clipping and casting:

```
while_level = 2**14 - 1  # bit depth = 14
output_image_data_8bpp = output_image_data.astype(np.float32) * (255 / (while_level - black_level))  # Scale to range [0, 255]
output_image_data_8bpp = output_image_data_8bpp.round().clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Convert to uint8 with rounding and clipping. (JPEG format must be uint8).
```

---

Updated code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image

def open_raw_file(raw_file_path, width, height):
    with open(raw_file_path, 'rb') as file:
        raw_data = file.read()

    # Assuming raw data is in RGB format, each pixel consists of 3 bytes (R, G, B)
    # Adjust the data format based on your specific raw file format if necessary
    #image_data = np.frombuffer(raw_data, dtype=np.uint8)
    image_data = np.frombuffer(raw_data, dtype=np.uint16)  # According to the readme.txt bpp = 16 (16 bits per pixel).
    #image_data = image_data.reshape((height, width, 3))
    image_data = image_data.reshape(height, width)  # The image is in raw Bayer format - before Demosaicing there is only one channel.

    return image_data

def apply_black_level_correction(image_data, black_level):
    corrected_image_data = np.maximum(image_data - black_level, 0)
    return corrected_image_data

def split_into_channels(image_data):
    red_channel = image_data[:, :, 0]
    green_channel = image_data[:, :, 1]
    blue_channel = image_data[:, :, 2]
    return red_channel, green_channel, blue_channel

def calculate_color_correction_matrix(image_data):
    # Assuming a 3x3 color correction matrix is required
    # Calculate the matrix based on your specific algorithm or requirements
    color_correction_matrix = np.eye(3)  # Identity matrix for demonstration purposes
    return color_correction_matrix

def save_image(image_data, output_path):
    image = Image.fromarray(image_data)
    image.save(output_path)

# Main code
raw_file_path = 'macbeth_2592x1944_RG.raw'
output_image_path = 'output_image13.jpg'

# The file name is macbeth_2592x1944_RG.raw so the width is 2592 and the height is 1944
width = 2592  # 640  # Adjust as per your raw file dimensions
height = 1944  # 480  # Adjust as per your raw file dimensions
black_level = 800 #20  # Note: According readme.txt black level equals 800 # Adjust the black level value as per your requirement

# Open raw file and convert it into an image
image_data = open_raw_file(raw_file_path, width, height)

# Apply black level correction (it's fine to apply black level correction before Demosaicing).
corrected_image_data = apply_black_level_correction(image_data, black_level)

# The file name is macbeth_2592x1944_RG so the Bayer patten is RGGB.
# Apply Demosaicing - convert from Bayer CFA to RGB
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(corrected_image_data, cv2.COLOR_BayerBG2RGB)  # COLOR_BayerBG2RGB gives the best results.

# Split into RGB channels
#red_channel, green_channel, blue_channel = split_into_channels(rgb_image) # (corrected_image_data)

# Calculate color correction matrix
color_correction_matrix = calculate_color_correction_matrix(corrected_image_data)

# Perform color correction
# Color correction scale [r, g, b] triplet by column vector (or row vector by [r, g, b] triplet)
red_channel_corrected = np.dot(rgb_image, color_correction_matrix[0])  #np.dot(red_channel, color_correction_matrix[0])
green_channel_corrected = np.dot(rgb_image, color_correction_matrix[1])  #np.dot(green_channel, color_correction_matrix[1])
blue_channel_corrected = np.dot(rgb_image, color_correction_matrix[2])  #np.dot(blue_channel, color_correction_matrix[2])

# Merge color channels back into image
output_image_data = np.stack((red_channel_corrected, green_channel_corrected, blue_channel_corrected), axis=2)

# According to readme.txt bit depth = 14
# We may assume that the white level is 2**14-1 = 16383.
# Convert from 16 bpp to 8 bits in range [0, 255] using linear transformation:  
while_level = 2**14 - 1  # bit depth = 14
output_image_data_8bpp = output_image_data.astype(np.float32) * (255 / (while_level - black_level))  # Scale to range [0, 255]
output_image_data_8bpp = output_image_data_8bpp.round().clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Convert to uint8 with rounding and clipping. (JPEG format must be uint8).

# Save the corrected image
save_image(output_image_data_8bpp, output_image_path)
```

---

Output image (downscaled):

[image]

Note:
The output is greenish due to the lack of color correction (this is normal).

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it. So how to make color correction? If there is matrix that contains 3 line of RGB values how should i multiply each pixel to them ?

Comment: I made color correction thank you it helped me a lot.

Comment: If you add the CCM (color correction matrix) to your question, I may add color correction to my answer (better also add the code the uses the matrix). We may also apply gamma correction for converting from linear color space to sRGB. It may help other users that stumble upon this post.